# SVG animation doesn't work after creating a duplicate

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

a client provided me 75 svg files to create an animation. Chatgpt wrote me a script that plays these images in the loop and it works pretty well. The thing is, that I need multiple animations like this on my website but the copies of this exact code dont move, they are static. What is wrong and how to make it move?

```
<style>
    /* Kontajner pre SVG obrázky */
    .svg-container {
      width: 7rem;
      height: 7rem;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* SVG obrázky */
    .animated-svg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    /* Kľúčová snímka s plným zobrazením */
    .animated-svg.active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="svg-container">
    <!-- Vložte sem všetkých 75 SVG obrázkov -->
    <!-- <img> kódy pre SVG obrázky tu... --><!-- Vložte sem ďalšie 59 SVG obrázkov (Livestream_00017.svg až Livestream_00075.svg) -->
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Livestream_00001.svg" class="animated-svg active" />
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Livestream_00002.svg" class="animated-svg" />
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Livestream_00003.svg" class="animated-svg" />
   <!-- the rest of the images... -->
  
</div>

  <script>
    const svgImages = document.querySelectorAll('.svg-container img.animated-svg');

    let currentFrame = 0;

    function showNextSvgImage() {
      svgImages.forEach(image => image.classList.remove('active')); // Skryje všetky obrázky

      currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % svgImages.length; // Zmení index na ďalší obrázok v kruhovej animácii

      svgImages[currentFrame].classList.add('active'); // Zobrazený obrázok
    }

    // Spustenie animácie po načítaní stránky
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      setInterval(showNextSvgImage, 20); // Meníme obrázok každých 20 milisekúnd (0,02 sekundy)
    });
  </script>
```

I tried prompting and asking chatgpt for help :)

Comment: There isn't enough code to tell what is going on, we at least need your failed implementation of the methods to help debug.

Comment: Just watch the page a bit longer and then **think** about what you see.